# Handle multiple byte array in amfphp

Tags: php, web-services, flash, apache-flex, amfphp

I working a app which is based on flash and php. I am trying to send image as byte array to amfphp in below format:

**

```
array(
'name'=>'Scott',
'age'=>29,
'image'=>array('first img byte array','second img byte array','so on..')
)
```

**

While, I am receiving the array from web services, I am getting {'data': null} by above format. But while I am sending only one bye array then everything working fine, below is my working format:

**

```
array(
'name'=>'Scott',
'age'=>29,
'image'=>'first img bye array'
)
```

**

Here is my function (PHP):

```
/**
 * Get Flash Object
 * (non-PHPdoc)
 * @param object $objectFormData
 * @return string url of uploaded image
 */
function sendFormData($objectFormData){     
    global $isAccessGranted;
    if ($isAccessGranted) {         
        if(is_object($objectFormData)){
            return $this->SaveAsJPEG($objectFormData);          
        }elseif(is_array($objectFormData)){
            $objectFormData = (object) $objectFormData;
            return $this->SaveAsJPEG($objectFormData);          
        }else{
            return "No Object or Array data type recived. it's ".gettype($objectFormData);
        }           
    } else {
        return 'Access Denied';
    }
}
```

Here is my SaveAsJPEG function:

```
/**
 * Save image from the given bytearray
 * and return the path of the saved image
 */
function SaveAsJPEG($ba, $compressed = false)
{
    if(!file_exists($this->output_dir) || !is_writeable($this->output_dir))
        trigger_error ("please create a 'flashupload' directory first with write access", E_USER_ERROR);            
    $data = $ba->data;
    if($compressed)
    {
        if(function_exists(gzuncompress))
        {
            $data = gzuncompress($data);
        } else {
            trigger_error ("gzuncompress method does not exists, please send uncompressed data", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    file_put_contents($this->output_dir . "/rawdata.jpeg", $data);
    return $this->server_url . $this->output_dir . "/rawdata.jpeg";
}
```

anybody can tell me that how can we handle multiple byt array data in amfphp.

**Thank you very much...**

Comment: How are you accessing the data at server end. Because your first array in 2D and second is 1D.

Comment: Hello Mr. Yogesh, See my updated question.

Comment: hi, what version are you using? I just tried with 2.1.1 and it worked ok it seems

Comment: Hi Ariel, I am also using 2.1.1 AMFPHP